# How to retrieve only enabled users from the Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to retrieve only enabled users in the AD. When I run this code line it returns the error. I tried using a filter as well to filter only enabled users for the requested info but it returns ALL users from every domain instead of just the single id.

```
Get-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'enabled -eq 'true''.
```

This is my code that is throwing the error.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Animal Shop A' | Get-ADUser -Filter '*' | Get-ADUser Where "enabled -eq 'true'" | Get-ADUser -Properties ('Mail')
```

This one returns ALL users from every domain

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Animal Shop A' | Get-ADUser -Filter "enabled -eq'true'" | Get-ADUser -Properties ('Mail')
```

Is my syntax wrong on both of them? If I just want to return values from say "Animal shop A" and then "Animal Shop B"

Comment: The entire issue here was that `"enabled -eq'true'"` should be `"enabled -eq $true"`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties mail | Where { $_.Enabled -eq $True} | Select Name,samaccountname,mail
```

That will get all enabled users in your target domain that are enabled and display the name, username, and mail properties

Comment: Note that this will ask AD for *every* user and only after all of those results are downloaded to your computer will the filtering will be done in memory. Olaf's answer will ensure you only ask AD for what you need, which saves time and memory.

Answer (score 20):

.. or a little bit shorter this way:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -Properties mail | 
    Select-Object -Property Name,samaccountname,mail
```

Besides this I would recommend to use a `-SearchBase`. That's  less stressful for the AD.  ;-)

Comment: Olaf for the win

Comment: ;-)  ... the result counts and that's the same. But thanks.

Comment: Shorter AND free of aliases! That's awesome mate.

Comment: Seems that the Enabled property is only set if you're running powershell with elevated priveledges.

Answer (score 1):

Important to know for both commands:
You must work with an elevated powershell process.
Otherwise the result may not be complete.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I had indeed incomplete results, but they looked okay for me. Without this answer, I would not have double checked with admin and gotten an incorrect report.

Answer (score 1):

```
get-aduser -filter 'enabled -eq "true"' -ResultSetSize $Null
```

Answer (score 0):

simply try below commands in powershell as administrator permission.
As a guide, the first part will filter users, second part filtered enabled users and last part will give you export of results.

`Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property Enabled | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -like “false”} | Export-Csv -Path C:\eport.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation`

hope to be useful for you.

Comment: Note that this will ask AD for *every* user and only after all of those results are downloaded to your computer will the filtering will be done in memory. Olaf's answer will ensure you only ask AD for what you need, which saves time and memory.